# How to filter rows for values that differ from each other in several columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

This is a piece of a larger dataframe I have:

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), 
                     C1 = c("5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "5", "7", "—", "—", "5"), 
                     C2 = c("5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "5", "—", "8", "—", "5"), 
                     C3 = c("5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "5", "—", "—", "9", "5"), 
                     C4 = c("5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "5", "—", "—", "9", "5")), 
                row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

| ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| B | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| C | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| D | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| E | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| F | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| G | 7 | — | — | — |
| H | — | 8 | — | — |
| I | — | — | 9 | 9 |
| J | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |

I want to filter only the rows from the last 4 columns that have different values among each other (e.g. rows 7:9). My first thought was to write a loop, but I know there's always a way around it in R. I've tried subsetting the numerical columns and using both `distinct()` and `unique()`. For some reason, though, rows like 1:6 still show up. I can't think of anything else yet. I'm very fond of pipes and `dplyr`. Would you guys know of any solution to this?

Comment: Hi, according to your comments, you said rows like: `7, 7, 8, 8`, or `9, 8, 9, 9` should appear in the end result, right? Could you explain why?

Comment: The full original df has thousands of rows... The majority of them have equal values in these 4 columns. A minority has missing values OR differing values. Rows with missing values resemble rows 1:6 in this sample. Rows with differing values should be like this example I gave, like 7, 7, 8, 8, or 9, 8, 9, 9 (representing values from columns C1:C4). These rows with missing or differing values are the ones my team is interested in... in the original dataframe, they are present. But I subsetted it before getting to this post, so these rows must have been filtered out in the process...

Comment: I'm actually checking this out right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `if_all`, you can choose to remove (`!`) rows `if_all` the columns are equal to the first (i.e. they are identical):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(!if_all(C1:C4, `==`, C1))

#  ID C1 C2 C3 C4
#1  G  7  —  —  —
#2  H  —  8  —  —
#3  I  —  —  9  9
```

Or with `if_any`, same logic:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(C1:C4, `!=`, C1))
```

Comment: Yesssss, this was exactly what I needed!!! Thank you so muchhhhhh!!!

Answer (score 3):

Or use `rowwise` filtering:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  rowwise() |>
  filter(n_distinct(c_across(-ID)) > 1) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  ID    C1    C2    C3    C4   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 G     7     —     —     —    
2 H     —     8     —     —    
3 I     —     —     9     9
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! Though... not all columns have a missing value... Some are, like: 7, 7, 8, 8, or... 9, 8, 9, 9. I noticed these rows don't appear in the end result =//

Comment: But I tried @Maël's suggestion and the result was the same, so I guess this must be because of the previous subset I did. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`

```
 df[!rowSums(df$C1[col(df[3:5])] == df[3:5]),]
```

-output

```
   ID C1 C2 C3 C4
7  G  7  —  —  —
8  H  —  8  —  —
9  I  —  —  9  9
```